# Django Admin: variables/constants inside Django Admin that can be changed

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to have variables/constants in Django Admin, that I can use later in code.

For example API keys, Google Tag manager identification number, etc.

I know I can set them in settings or other file, but this are more for marketing team and can be changed.

How this can be done ? are just single record variable(not multiple - so Models is not the best solution)

Comment: simply add an individual field for each?

Comment: You might find one of the packages on https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/live-setting/ useful.

Comment: @Max M - can you elaborate,give me a link ? If I use a model with multiple fields, I can add as many models as I want I want this to not be possible

Comment: @Alasdair I checked but none of them are compatible with Django 1.11

Comment: Are you sure none of them are compatible with Django 1.11? Django-packages might be out of date. The very first one in the list [appears to test Django 1.11](https://django-constance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html#v2-0-2017-02-17).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

then do something like:

```
class myConstant(models.Model)
    # ...

    def clean(self):
        if self.id: # instance already exists
            # do some clean
        elif myConstant.objects.count() > 0:
            raise ValidationError("Only one instance allowed")
        else:
            # do some clean

    def save(self):
        # check if this instance already exists
        if self.id:
           super().save()
        # else: count numbers of all instances of this model
        elif myConstant.objects.all().count() > 0:
            return # no save will be processed
        else:
            super().save()
```

This way you have only 1 allowed instance for this mode - which can exist of only 1 field that is your constant value.

You can go more save and not only check if your current instance already exists, but check if your current instance is that one instance you may already have.

```
if myConstant.objects.count() > 0 and myConstant.objects.all[0] == self:
    # do some clean in case of clean() method
    super().save() # in case of save method
```

Additionally, if you want to use this constant represented by a model anywhere in your app/project, you simply must provide ForeignKeys from other models to this, where it is necessary.